# Specify default value where no matching JOINed record

Tags: sql, oracle, join, reporting

A colleague is trying to produce a report in an ERP system with a custom reporting function; the underlying DB is Oracle 11g. The significant fact here is that the ERP reporting function *might* limit the approaches we can take for this report. That is my colleagues suspicion, but I don't know enough about it to confirm this.

**The Problem:**
We have a table detailing positions within the company, which we will call `Roles`, and another table storing who is assigned to each role for given time windows, and we'll call this `PersonRoles`.

For a given date, we want to return the person or people (there could be multiple people fulfilling the same role at the same time) who have a particular role.

However, sometimes roles will be vacant for a period; for example, if PersonA holds the role from Jan - May, and PersonB holds the role from Aug - Dec, there will be a 2 month windows where nobody was within post. In this case, when we query by such a day (Jun/Jul), we want to return a standard result (say 'Vacant').

Not only would I be interested to hear the 'best' approach, but other approaches might be better suited to the supposed limitations of this reporting tool, so they would be welcome too.

Comment: I'd forgotten about this Qn - I'd passed across the suggestion to my colleague, and forgotten about it. I no longer work there (nor does he as it happens) so I've no idea what the end solution was; so I've selected the most 'complete' of the two answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without knowing the limitations of the reporting tool, it's obviously hard to answer this question.  The simplest approach, though, would be to do an outer join.  Something along the lines of

```
SELECT r.role_name,
       nvl( pr.person_name, 'Vacant' )
  FROM roles r
       LEFT OUTER JOIN personRoles pr  
         ON(    r.role_id = pr.rold_id
            AND <<some date parameter>> BETWEEN pr.start_date AND pr.end_date)
```

Comment: I appreciate the lack of knowledge of the reporting tools is a barrier, and I can't even say whether the perceived constraints are real or imagined. Hence why a range of solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Left outer join from the `Roles` to the `PersonRoles` table on the Role ID *and* the date period. Include a `coalesce(PersonRoles.PersonIdentifier,'Vacant')` item.